# Warning: Database is not up to date! in joomla

Tags: mysql, database, joomla

I am new in joomla. I'm using joomla version 3.5 and facing 3 database problem

1. Table 'jos_menu' does not have index 'idx_client_id_parent_id_alias_language'. (From file 2.5.0-2011-12-24.sql.)
2. Table 'jos_redirect_links' does not have index 'idx_old_url'. (From file 3.5.0-2016-03-01.sql.)
   3 .The Joomla! Core database tables have not been converted yet to UTF-8 Multibyte (utf8mb4).

and in other information tab I'm getting these warnings :

1. Database schema version (in #__schemas): 3.5.1-2016-03-29.
2. Update version (in #__extensions): 3.5.1.
3. Database driver: mysqli.
4. 91 database changes were checked successfully.
5. 145 database changes did not alter table structure and were skipped.

Please help!!

This is the code I'm using in the template

```
<?php
    defined('_JEXEC') or die;

    $app             = JFactory::getApplication();
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <jdoc:include type="head" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/style/style.css" />


            </head>

            <body>

                <?php if($this->countModules('banner')) : ?>
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="banner" style="none"/>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if($this->countModules('service')) : ?>
                <div class="body">
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="service" style="none"/>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </body>
        </html>
```

and this is the templateDetails.xml code:

Custom Template
        1.0
        6/2/2016
        Test
        admin@joomla.org
        Copyright (C) 2005 - 2016 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
        Custom Template for joomla website

```
    <files>
        <folder>html</folder>
        <folder>images</folder>
        <folder>style</folder>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
        <filename>index.php</filename>
        <filename>templateDetails.xml</filename>
    </files>

    <positions>
        <position>service</position>
        <position>banner</position>
        <position>about</position>
    </positions>

    <config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="general" label="General">
                <field name="logo_txt"
                        type="image"
                        label="Logo"
                        description="Enter your logo"
                />

                <field name="copyright_txt"
                        type="text"
                        label="copyright text"
                        description="Enter your copyright text"
                />
            </fieldset>
        </fields>
    </config>
</extension>
```

Comment: Share your relevant code so that other users can check.

Comment: I've added the code that I've used in the template.. are you looking for this code ?

Comment: You should try adding index to your tables.